# Update textView from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

In my OnCreate method I have created a thread that listens to incoming message!

```
In OnCreate() {

//Some code

myThread = new Thread() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                receiveMyMessages();

            }
        };
myThread.start();

// Some code related to sending out by pressing button etc.

}

Then, receiveMyMessage() functions…

Public void receiveMyMessage()
{

//Receive the message and put it in String str;

str = receivedAllTheMessage();

// <<    here I want to be able to update this str to a textView. But, How?
}
```

I checked [this article](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog) but it did not work for me, no luck!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any updates to the UI in an Android application must happen in the UI thread.  If you spawn a thread to do work in the background you must marshal the results back to the UI thread before you touch a View.  You can use the `Handler` class to perform the marshaling:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    // Handler gets created on the UI-thread
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // This gets executed in a non-UI thread:
    public void receiveMyMessage() {
        final String str = receivedAllTheMessage();
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify Views
                mTextView.setText(str);
            }
        });
}
```

The `AsyncTask` class simplifies a lot of the details for you and is also something you could look into.  For example, I believe it provides you with a thread pool to help mitigate some of the cost associated with spawning a new thread each time you want to do background work.

Comment: Hello all, thank you, thank you very much for your time. Yet no luck! I am trying to rephrase my question:-  (together with the original question)

In the OnCreate called receiveMyMessage() in a thread! That means this receiveMyMessage is in a separate thread. In this thread, I have a while loop, that is reading if there is any message!

public void receiveMessages() {

while loop ( conditions)  
{

str = receivedAllTheMessage();

// Now, here I want to update GUI elements tv.settext ... etc..

}

}

Comment: **Additional tip on this answer:** You can skip creating the separate handler by using the Activity's handler object.  `handler = getWindow().getDecorView().getHandler();`

Comment: @Kent That tip may or may not work, depending where you use it. I found that tip elsewhere on the Internet, and made use of it, and then when I changed some things in my program it suddenly didn't work anymore. See here for more info: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/114723/92925

Answer (score 0):

Android supports message-passing concurrency using handlers and sendMessage(msg). (It is also possible to use handlers for shared-memory concurrency.) One tip is to call thread.setDaemon(true) if you wish the thread to die when the app dies. The other tip is to have only one handler and use message.what and a switch statement in the message handler to route messages.

[Code](https://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/playing-around-with-threads) and [Code](https://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/asynch)