# setText is not updating

Tags: android

Here is the code and i want to setText the Array of Textview after the random Images selected.. its not updating the textVew.  I am passing Context and view to the constructor of this class of my other activity ? this is non activity class how to achieve the same?

```
public class DisplayObject {
    Random _randomGenerator = new Random();
    int hudDisplay[] = {
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element1,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element2,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element3,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element4,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element5,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element6,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element7
    };

    static View[] _hiddenObjects;
    int NO_OF_OBJECTS = 15;
    TextView[] _HudTextDisplay = new TextView[7];

    public HiddenObject(Context context, View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View huddisplay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gameplay, null);
        /*NO_OF_OBJECTS = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NO_OF_OBJECTS_AVAILABLE_PER_LEVEL);*/
        _hiddenObjects = new View[NO_OF_OBJECTS];
        random();

        for (int i = 0; i < hudDisplay.length; ++i) {
            _HudTextDisplay[i] = (TextView) huddisplay.findViewById(hudDisplay[i]);
            _HudTextDisplay[i].setText(_hiddenObjects[i].getTag().toString());
        }
    }

    public void random() {
        List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_OBJECTS; ++i) {
            while (true) {
                Integer next = _randomGenerator.nextInt(GamePlayActivity._hiddenObjects.length);
                if (!generated.contains(next)) {
                    _hiddenObjects[i] = GamePlayActivity._hiddenObjects[next];
                    Log.d("Check", "Image is " + _hiddenObjects[i].getTag());

                    generated.add(next);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to setText the textview ?

Comment: can you give me value of _hiddenObjects[i].getTag().toString() for all

Comment: Put a break point on the `.setText()` line and run the debugger. Is it actually getting called?

Comment: @Samir The value of all the Tags is Image1,image2 and so on .. I am getting the output in myconsole but not updated in my UI

Comment: @TheLastBert :  I am getting the output in myconsole but not updated in my UI

Comment: Just a reminder to other readers, double check the visibility of TextView if not update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for anyone who is having this problem, you may have to place your setText method inside this

```
    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((EditText)editText).setText(text);
        }
    });
```

Comment: any idea why? I didn't have this problem before

Comment: This solved my problem on an activity where the camera is in preview mode on part of the activity and I need to update other views in the same activity.

Comment: Not Working in my case.

Comment: Got this problem on API level 19. No problems on 21+. This solution helped, but I would appreciate if anybody explains why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `postInvalidate()` **after** `setText(...)`, not in advance !

```
 ...
 _HudTextDisplay[i].setText(_hiddenObjects[i].getTag().toString());
 _HudTextDisplay[i].postInvalidate();
 ...
```

Comment: I've never had to call `postInvalidate()` on a text view after calling `setText()`.

Comment: @TheLastBert : then how do u do it ? How to setText in above thing its not getting updated

Comment: @user1201239 Is this class being used outside the UI-Thread ? If that's the case you have to use handler for example .. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400288/update-textview-from-thread-please-help