# Destroying and Reconstructing FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter that displays a variable number of fragments. The onCreateView method of each Fragment within it looks something like:

```
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (container == null)
        return null;

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting TextView text to: " + someString);
    tv.setText(someString); // Where someString is some global that will change later.
}
```

Next, I change someString to some new value.
Then I reconstruct the FragmentPagerAdapter. My intent is to destroy the old one and start fresh:

```
mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(...);
mMyViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

My debug statement in the Fragment shows the new value of the string as expected, yet the TextView is still displaying the old value of the string.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

My TextView is actually an EditText, so I started searching for why an EditText might not refresh, and StackOverflow came to the rescue again:

[EditText Settext not working with Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303469/edittext-settext-not-working-with-fragment)

Turns out that EditText has a problem refreshing in the onCreateView method of a Fragment. So I moved my code out of onCreateView and into onStart and it worked!

I'd love to know why an EditText can't refresh in onCreateView though. That's just bizzare.

Answer (score 0):

that probably because you using the regular `FragmentManager`.  Try to hand to the constructor of your `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` instance of `ChildFragmentManager`.

```
mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

**Edit**:
If you use `FragmentActivity` try to add:

```
 viewPager.removeAllViews();
 viewPager.setAdapter(null);
```

before setting the new `Adapter`.

Comment: I'm constructing MyFragmentPagerAdapter from a FragmentActivity. I don't have access to a child fragment manager. I'm passing it getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: See me edited answer. Anyway why you don't just update the TextView instead of all the mass?

Comment: Still not working. Bizarre thing is that I can set the text color and visibility and it changes. But setting the text itself has no effect. BTW, once I do set the text, when I call getText on the TextView, it returns the new value. But it's displaying the old value!

Comment: That because you call it on the new Adapter while it display the old one

Comment: I fixed the problem. See my answer. Thanks for your suggestions.