# Android View Binding cannot setText in EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I have got a layout with several edit fields from material design and standard EditText. User can enter value from keyboard and and press 'calculate'. After that the values in those EditText should be replaced with new calculated values. I'm trying to use setText but the values don't change in EditText. It seems that setText is only working with TextView fields. I also noticed that I can only set the text once on first Fragment open.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/inputLayout"
    android:hint="@string/txtWindSpeed">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/setting1"
        style="@style/layoutTextDecimal"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/setting2"
    style="@style/inputLayout"
/>
```

I'm using viewBinding accorging to Android documentation

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return bind.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Here I try to set value. I print it just before setText and I can see correct number, but the edit field is not updated.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (...)
    println(variable.toString())
    bind.setting1.setText(variable.toString())
    bind.setting2.setText(variable.toString())
}
```

I've got all newest versions of following modules. I'm also sure that my code was working with previous versions of some of those modules, but I don't remember which one has changed since then.

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I am not an expert in Android and Kotlin and this is quite an annoying issue for me to understand what is going on.

EDIT:
I went back to version 2.3

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'.
```

There is a big difference and my problems seem to disappear. Maybe I did something wrong but the fragments behave differently in version 2.4. It seems like the fragments remember state but not always. In random circumstances I got old variables displayed. I tried to use:

```
app:popUpToSaveState="false"
app:restoreState="false"
```

in nav_graph but it didn't help. Also had a strange behaviour of bottom navigation menu, where I had to click the icon twice to go back to HomeFragment. In 2.3.5 there are no such problems.

Comment: _"User can enter value from keyboard and and press 'calculate'. After that the values in those EditText should be replaced with new calculated values"_ The only `setText` calls you've shown us are the ones you have in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Yes Michael. At this point I'm changing the "variable" which is global. When I open another fragment and then open the first fragment I see old values in edit Text. I don't understand why it is not updated in onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

Also there's an issue in onActivityCreated. I reset edittext's content in onStart or onResume and it works.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303469/edittext-settext-not-working-with-fragment) to view discussion...