# TextView.setText() doesn't update text in ExpandableListView adapter

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I wrote a class that extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. When a group is clicked, I want it to expand, and then my custom indicator in the view will animate a 180 rotation. And it works.

My problem is that on the same `clicklistener` I want to update a `TextView` using `setText()` method, but when I run it, it doesn't update the view.
I tested if the problem was in the reference to the `TextView`: changing the visibility, rotating it, animating it, and they all work. Its just the `setText()` that doesn't works.
Here is the relevant code in the adapter class: (There are actually two `TextViews` I would like to update)

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
    GroupViewHolder holder = mViewHolderSparseArray.get(groupPosition);
    Lesson lesson = (Lesson) getChild(groupPosition, 0);
    holder.indicatorView.animate().rotation(180);
    holder.teacherView.setText(lesson.getTeacher());
    holder.classroomView.setText(lesson.getClassroom());
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
    GroupViewHolder holder = mViewHolderSparseArray.get(groupPosition);
    holder.indicatorView.animate().rotation(0);
    holder.teacherView.setText("...");
    holder.classroomView.setText("");
}
```

I have also tried to put this code in the getGroupView() (assign an OnClickListener to the view), but I get the same results.

Some other relevant methods:

```
@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas why my `TextView` doesn't update its text?

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged ();` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281494/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I don't see how the notifyDataSetChanged() would help (tried it, didn't work), but the answer you linked helped. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer linked by @IntelliJAmiya, The setText() doesn't update because it probably didn't run on the UI thread.

Here Is what I did to fix this issue:

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
    final GroupViewHolder holder = mViewHolderSparseArray.get(groupPosition);
    final Lesson lesson = (Lesson) getChild(groupPosition, 0);
    holder.indicatorView.animate().rotation(180);
    holder.teacherView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.teacherView.setText(lesson.getTeacher());
            holder.classroomView.setText(lesson.getClassroom());
        }
    });
}
```