# Displaying dynamic Textview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to created a chat application based on smack library. I think my issue has nothing to do with this library as logcat sends and receives everything correctly. My problem is when i receive a message it does not display. Following is the method i'm using to display text.

```
public void TextCreating(String message) {

    Log.d("START", "Method Excution started.");

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(message);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    Log.d("STARTED", "Text color OK.");
    layout.addView(tv);
    Log.d("STARTED", "Text didsplayed.");
}
```

This peace of code will be executed as a message received. Those received messages are handled through a listener called PacketListener. This receiving part is working fine. In this listener when i call above TextCreating method it executes up to   tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); Last line does not executes. What is the reason for this? How can I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chat Room"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Chat History :" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutLinear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'line does not executes'? if it was compiled and uploaded to the device it should be executed if no exception occurred before it. Have You tried to set breakpoint in the debugger to it?

Comment: Log.d("STARTED", "Text didsplayed."); does not log. But Log.d("STARTED", "Text color OK."); logs. As I feel that means layout.addView(tv); does not executes...

Comment: is layoutLinear just a normal LinearLayout and not some extended version? Is where any exception in the log after 'Text color OK.'?

Comment: Layout is just a normal LinearLayout. There are no exceptions after  'Text color OK.'. If it receives a new message again the same thing happens again without errors.

Comment: I get confused. Is the issue persistent or it's just 'some messages randomly not displayed'?

Comment: this is not a random issue. Above method does not display any message that i receives. but it does not disturb the process of sending and receiving messages. Anytime i can send or receive messages(logcat shows me each received and sent message). but nothing displayed in the emulator "layoutLinear". that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, did you try  printing `message` on logcat?

Comment: could You share Your layout xml file please?

Comment: @ sandrstar : I edited the post. check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thank u every one for your ideas and helps. I solver this by introducing a Handler to the code. I was trying to do everything in my UI thread. So i modified my code as follows.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public void TextCreating(final String message) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tv = new TextView(MUCchat.this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.append(message);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            layout.addView(tv);
        }
    });     
}
```

This link helped me a lot to figureout this.
[Update textView from thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400288/update-textview-from-thread-please-help)

Comment: Do You say what You've tried to update it not from UI Thread? Usually (seems, not always, e.g. not on old android version) have lead to an exception, but You've mentioned no exception observed...

Comment: yes, that was the problem. I'm developing this for API10 and there were no exception on this issue as i told u earlier. Message sending and receiving worked at the logcat though they were not displayed on the emulator. thank u very much sandrstar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution to create a chat box.
Its usings `ListView`. add item as a new `message` arrives.

```
android:stackFromBottom
```

can be set to true, to make it exactly like a chat box. by default it has scrolling also.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this chat application may contain messages with radio buttons, check boxes and etc. in that condition it might be difficult to use this method as the solution for this. here i have tried the basic text chat only. anyway thanks for the idea...

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK has a sample chat application which communicates through bluetooth.
You can take a look at on a code.

It uses a `ListView` to display Conversations

Hope this answer is useful :)

Comment: thanks for the idea. But i want to know why above issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've run Yours code on the device and observed no issue with it. I've did timer calls to `TextCreating(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " next call\n");` and was able to observe text in the black LinearLayout.
The only issue I can see with that I see is that `LinearLayout` won't scroll. So, if You add more text it won't be visible.