# ASyncTask trouble - An error occured while executing doInBackground

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm having some trouble with an AsyncTask. Im trying to reach a php-file thats supposed to connect and check with a MySQL db if username is correct.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
12-01 14:51:25.815: W/dalvikvm(3216): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6309)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at com.example.obligatorisk.MainActivity$loader.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at com.example.obligatorisk.MainActivity$loader.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-01 14:51:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(3216):     ... 5 more
```

(Sorry for the wall of text, not sure whats nessecary to include)

**The code I am working with:**

```
protected class loader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {



        try {


            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/phplogin.php");

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_in",username.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_in",password.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.getEntity().consumeContent();

            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
            {

                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.obligatorisk.BROWSER"));

            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Could someone help me out here? I've been stuck for days.

Answer (score 1):

Xortrox you get an exception because you're trying to update UI from not UI thread, so there are two ways of solving it: first you can pass your activity as a parameter to AsyncTask and use activity's [runOnUiThread method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update UI, but this way lacks some grace.

The other way is to use asynchronous way of interaction (AsyncTask is made for this=)), AsyncTask has [onPreExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) and [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) methods which are run in UI thread, so I suggest you to change the return type of your AsyncTask to either HttpResponse or String and then do any processing and updating UI in onPostExecute, as for me this way is the best

Answer (score 0):

The logs says that the code at line `com.example.obligatorisk.MainActivity$loader.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)` tries to modify the View, but is running in a different thread.

The idea with `AsyncTask` is that `doInBackground` rus in a different thread: it cannot change the Views created in the main thread. That's why you have `preExecute` and `postExecute`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException
```

because:

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I don't have a solution to your problem but I could possibly point you in the right direction.I assume you are trying to change a view from a separate thread, which wont work.
I believe you have to figure out how to change an android view from a separate thread.
I also did a quick google and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400288/update-textview-from-thread-please-help)

The top answer seems to be doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put these lines inside doinbackground

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_in",**username.getText().toString().trim()**));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_in",**password.getText().toString().trim()**));
```

so get data before task start and pass value to the asyntask...

Answer (score 0):

The error is you cant call username.gettext().tostring(),password.getText().toString() like these..
try to get the values in a string before calling AsyncTask and use it..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in

```
username.getText().toString().trim())
```

username is a TextView? (At least the [getText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) is from there)

You cannot access any View objects from a non UI thread. PERIOD.

Store the username and password in a field before starting the AsyncTask or create a constructor in loader class to accept username and password, and store them in fields in the loader class(preferable solution).

Answer (score 0):

AS the exception:

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

So, we can know what is wrong with the code.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_in",username.getText().toString().trim()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_in",password.getText().toString().trim()));
```

Please make sure no ui code is there in doInBackground.
As long as you require to access the UI, Please put the code into onPostExecute method