# Making a simple counter that increments every second on android. What wrong am I doing?

Tags: android, multithreading, counter

Im writing code to display a counter that increments by 1 every second.

The app is getting forced closed before running with the error -

**thread exiting with uncaught exception**  and  **No package identifier when getting value for resource number**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler hand = new Handler();
    TextView ti;
    int i =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           i++;
           ti.setText(i);
        }
    };
}
```

What wrong am I doing ?

Comment: Here `ti.setText(i);` use `ti.setText(String.valueOf(i));`

Comment: you have to do it with handlers. You cant actualize UI out from UI Thread. Please, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400288/update-textview-from-thread-please-help

Comment: @oPi .. Thanks a lot. I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 no problem. You just have to distinguish whats done in the main thread and whats not

Comment: @oPi there is only one thread here: the main UI thread

Comment: @pskink what runnable does?

Comment: @oPi nothing: it's just an interface

Comment: @pskink well, Oracle disagree: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: Im reading more about making new threads hoping to not to make mistakes like these and as of now, the answer below is working.

Comment: `Handler.postDelayed()` causes the runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the UI thread.

Comment: @oPi well, i disagree: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Runnable.java how is it suppose to make any new thread?

Comment: @oPi instead ask, what `postDelayed` does.

Comment: @pskink as in your link: `Represents a command that can be executed. Often used to run code in a different {@link Thread}.`. You cant assure in any moment that the code is on the main thread

Comment: @oPi Runnable is just an interface, it has NOTHING to do with any thread creation, it can be used anywhere to implement something that can be "run"

Comment: @pskink Oracle says yes, your link says yes and you can find more info easily (just search `java thread vs runnable`). In the other hand you say no...

Comment: @oPi ok just create an interface in the file Runnable.java with the content: "public interface Runnable { public void run(); }" please tell me how it can have anything to do with java threading...

Comment: @oPi if you still believe that "public void run()" from the code above is run in non UI thread just call: Log.d(TAG, "thread: " + Thread.currentThread()); inside run method and maybe that will be a good proof that you are wrong, EOT from me

Comment: @pskink sorry, some missunderstood by my side. Next time lest argue on my language xD

Comment: @oPi i don't know spanish at all...

Comment: @pskink so ill improve my english. Sorry again for the missunderstanding

Comment: @oPi its ok, at least now we agree

Comment: @pskink if i started using translator before we would agree from the beggining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `textView.setText(int id)` takes an int as parameter. For e.g. `R.string.app-name`. When you pass `i` as parameter, it will check for id `i` in `strings.xml`. `TextView` also provides an overloaded method `setText(CharSequence text)`, which you can use here.

`textView.setText(""+i);` **or** `textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));`

Comment: yes. done. Im reading more about new threads. Its been just a month that I'm coding in android. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`ti.setText(i)` is trying to resolve a resource by the value of i.
Try `ti.setText(String.valueOf(i));` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a precise timer, you should calculate a difference, from when started a timer, increment a variable in every call is not a accurate solution, here is the code, if you want a precise timer

```
private long startTime;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            textView.setText(Long.toString(diff / 1000));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```